# Find logarithmic equation from a graph but line only clearly passes through one point

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I'm working through an online textbook, currently 'graphs of logarithmic functions' on [this page, try it #11 right underneath example 11](https://openstax.org/books/algebra-and-trigonometry/pages/6-4-graphs-of-logarithmic-functions).

For the example before the question, the page shows an example of solving by taking two points on the graph:
[image]

This works because there are two clear points on the graph. Then the book provides an opportunity to reinforce the learning with an exercise, #11:

[image]

This function only passes through one integer point, (-2,-1). Given that, how can I fins the function using the method I was just shown in example 11?

Comment: I'd skip the problem

Comment: The general form of a logarithm is $y=a\ln(x+b)+c$, which requires three pieces of data to find all the coefficients.  Here, you have the asymptote and the point, but there aren't any other clear pieces of data, so it seems that this approach does not illustrate the technique.

Comment: Thanks both for the sanity check, I was pretty frustrated with this one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question asks for a natural logarithm, whereas the first question asks for a common logarithm.  I think that the intent here is that the general form of the logarithm would be $y=\ln(x+b)+c$ and not $y=a\ln(x+b)+c$.  The reason is that if the coefficient in front of the $\ln$ is not $1$, then the function could be rewritten as a logarithm with respect to a different base.  In particular, the second form could be written as
$$
y=\log_{e^a}(x+b)+c.
$$
This assumption is not stated in the book (through a simple search), but it makes the problem possible (and provides some ideas for the alternate phrasing).  Therefore, we'll consider the form
$$
y=\ln(x+b)+c.
$$
In this case, it seems that there is enough data in the problem (using the asymptote and the point on the curve).

My solution:

> It appears that $x=-3$ is a vertical asymptote, so $b=3$ in our general form and we're interested in $y=\ln(x+3)+c$.

> The point $(-2,-1)$ is on the logarithm, so $-1=\ln(-2+3)+c$ or that $-1=\ln(1)+c$, which simplifies to $-1=c$, since $\ln(1)=-1$.

Comment: Thank you! As a learner, I find the books excercise confusing and don't think I would have been able to solve this on my own. I wish they had given me a chance to reinforce my learning with a question similar to the example they provided, before giving me a more challenging one like this